# How to make a gameobject locate others gameobjects positions and tell their color?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 gameobjects, one blue and red. Both of them are running around the scene with limits on the camera, so they can't go pass a certain area.

And if possible i would like to know how to move them on the diagonal as well.

This is my entire code.

```
public Transform Objectup;
public Transform Objectdown;
public Transform Objectright;
public Transform Objectleft;
public DirectionGameObject direction;
public int speed = 2;



public enum DirectionGameObject
{
    Right,
    Left,
    Up,
    Down
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    direction = SortdirectionGameObject(direction);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    Destroy();

    if(direction == DirectionGameObject.Right)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        if(transform.position.x >= Objectright.position.x)
        {
            direction = SortdirectionGameObject(direction);
        }
    }

    if(direction == DirectionGameObject.Left)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        if(transform.position.x <= Objectleft.position.x)
        {
            direction = SortdirectionGameObject(direction);
        }
    }

    if(direction == DirectionGameObject.Up)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        if(transform.position.y >= Objectup.position.y)
        {
            direction = SortdirectionGameObject(direction);
        }
    }

    if(direction == DirectionGameObject.Down)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        if(transform.position.y <= Objectdown.position.y)
        {
            direction = SortdirectionGameObject(direction);
        }
    }
}

private DirectionGameObject SortdirectionGameObject(DirectionGameObject maindirection)
{
    DirectionGameObject directionSorted = maindirection;

    do{
        int newDirection = Random.Range((int)DirectionGameObject.Right, (int)DirectionGameObject.Down + 1);
        directionSorted = (DirectionGameObject)newDirection;

    } while (maindirection == directionSorted);

    return directionSorted;
}

void Destroy()
{
    Destroy(gameObject,120.0f);
}
```

I need to show on the console their color and position when i press G and V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colour property of a GameObject that you are looking for resides in the material of the Renderer component.

It can be referenced in this way:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color
```

In order to get the Renderer component of a GameObject, you must have a reference to it, for example:

```
GameObject object1;
GameObject object2;
```

You can then get the color of each object like so:

```
Color color1 = object1.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
```

You can then check the value of the color like so:

```
if (color1 == Color.red){

    // Do something

}
```

Or, if you want to display their color to the console:

```
Debug.Log(color1);
```

Colors are stored as 4 floating point values, so if you want to output "color is red" or "color is blue", you will need an equivalence check, like I provided above with the "// Do something" comment.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I know, but i need to be another gameobject to do so. By instantiating a prefab.

Comment: Edited answer for you with more info

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a method for getting the material color of an Gameobject But you can name the Gameobject as the color it has, since the color is static and not changing and you can use   Gameobject.name method , And for locating other gameobjects you can use transform.Lookat

Comment: public Transform target
public float speed;


void FixedUpdate(){
transform.Lookat(target);
transform.position+=transform.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime;


}